# Keras Hyperband Search Using Directory Iterator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

I am using Tensorflow's `flow_from_directory` to collect a large image dataset and then train on it. I want to use Keras Tuner but when I run

```
tuner.search(test_data_gen, epochs=50, 
              validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[stop_early])
```

It throws the following error,

```
ValueError: `validation_split` is only supported for Tensors or NumPy arrays, found following types in the input: [<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator'>]
```

I don't know much about converting between data types in AI so any help is truly appreciated.

Here is the rest of my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import IPython.display as display
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence
import os
import pathlib
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import cv2
import datetime
import kerastuner as kt

tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()

epochs = 50
steps_per_epoch = 10
batch_size = 20
IMG_HEIGHT = 200
IMG_WIDTH = 200

train_dir = "Data/Train"
test_dir = "Data/Val"

train_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

test_image_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_data_gen = train_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                           directory=train_dir,
                                                           shuffle=True,
                                                           target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                           class_mode='sparse')

test_data_gen = test_image_generator.flow_from_directory(batch_size=batch_size,
                                                         directory=test_dir,
                                                         shuffle=True,
                                                         target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                         class_mode='sparse')


    def model_builder(hp):
        model = keras.Sequential()
        model.add(Conv2D(265, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D())
        model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
        model.add(MaxPooling2D())
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
        hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=32, max_value=512, step=32)
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(hp_units, activation="relu"))
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(80, activation="softmax"))
    
        hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
    
        model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
                      loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                      metrics=['top_k_categorical_accuracy'])
    
        return model
    
    tuner = kt.Hyperband(model_builder,
                         objective='val_accuracy',
                         max_epochs=30,
                         factor=3,
                         directory='Hypertuner_Dir',
                         project_name='AIOS')
    
    stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
```

and start searching with `tuner`

```
tuner.search(train_data_gen, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[stop_early])

# Get the optimal hyperparameters
best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]

print(f"""
The hyperparameter search is complete. The optimal number of units in the first densely-connected
layer is {best_hps.get('units')} and the optimal learning rate for the optimizer
is {best_hps.get('learning_rate')}.
""")

model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

model.summary()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, to_file="model.png", show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB')
checkpoint_path = "training/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

os.system("rm -r logs")

log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)

#history = model.fit(train_data_gen,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,epochs=epochs,validation_data=test_data_gen,validation_steps=10,callbacks=[cp_callback, tensorboard_callback])
history = model.fit(train_data_gen,steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,epochs=epochs,validation_split=0.2,validation_steps=10,callbacks=[cp_callback, tensorboard_callback])
model.load_weights(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir))
model.save('model.h5', include_optimizer=True)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_data_gen)
print("Tested Acc: ", test_acc)
print("Tested Acc: ", test_acc*100, "%")

val_acc_per_epoch = history.history['val_accuracy']
best_epoch = val_acc_per_epoch.index(max(val_acc_per_epoch)) + 1
print('Best epoch: %d' % (best_epoch,))
```

===================================**EDIT**====================================
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/) about `validation_split`:

> **validation_split**: Float between 0 and 1. Fraction of the training data to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch. The validation data is selected from the last samples in the x and y data provided, before shuffling. This argument is not supported when x is a dataset, generator or keras.utils.Sequence instance.

Now, as you've generator, try as follows, [reference](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/104#issuecomment-636399986)

```
tuner.search(train_data_gen, 
             epochs=50, 
             validation_data=test_data_gen, 
             callbacks=[stop_early])
```

Also, ensure that each of your generators properly generates the valid batches.

Comment: Wait, so I use the ```image_dataset_from_directory``` or ```flow_from_directory```?

Comment: I think, `flow_from_dir..`., the one you already mentioned in your above code.

Comment: P.S. please clean your code above, it's hard to read. Just paste the most relevant part.

Comment: Oh, I see what you guys are saying! I can't do validation split for ```tuner.search``` because I have an iterator. I need to instead make the validation split beforehand and then pimply pass it!

Comment: can you check: `tuner.search(train_data_gen)` and `tuner.search(test_data_gen)` and see if it runs normally?

Comment: Now it says "Filling up shuffle buffer" and my computer is frozen. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: for both? or specific?

Comment: I am attaching a screenshot to the question.

Comment: for which command? `tuner.search(train_data_gen)` or `tuner.search(test_data_gen)`?

Comment: I am not sure. I will try and see if I can figure out which command is freezing it.

Comment: What I meant is to check. First, run this `tuner.search(train_data_gen)` and see what happens? If it runs normally then try next with `test_data_gen`. But If any error shows, then inform here.

Comment: It is freezing at ```tuner.search(train_ds, epochs=50, validation_data=test_ds, callbacks=[stop_early])```

Comment: I fixed it! I just needed to disable shuffling on my batch generator because my computer can't handle it. Thank you so much for the help. I truly appreciate it!

Comment: But note that, you should set `shuffle=True` for `train_data_gen` and set `False` for test_data_gen`.

Comment: I will try that and see if my computer lives to tell the tale!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately doing a `validation_split=0.2` does not work in this case, because this argument assumes that the data is a Tensor or a NumPy array. Since you have the data stored as a generator (which is a good idea), you can't simply split it.

You'll need to create a validation generator, just like you did with test_data_gen, and change `validation_split=0.2` to `validation_data=val_data_gen`.

Comment: I think I tried that but it still didn't work. I made 2 separate generators with completely different data directories but it still didn't work.

Comment: with validation data generator, what error it gave?